# WPF TextBox - German letter ß automatically replaced with ü

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, textbox

We'd added German localization to our WPF Application and later we've got a feedback from one of our German users. He told us that he was unable to input German letter "ß" - it was automatically replaced with letter "ü".

Looking forward to hear some answers or suggestions.

Issue example screenshot:
[image: issue example screenshot]

Comment: I have a feeling this the font you are using does not have the Eszett character and therefore it is being replaced with umlauted u.  The default font for WPF is Segoe UI which has support for Eszett but perhaps you are using a different font.

Comment: I've not even thought about it. We definitely have custom fonts. But if I copy this symbol I can paste it into the textbox and it will be displayed correctly. Anyway, thank you - I'll try to research if it's connected with our fonts.

Comment: I've had this problem many times with Persian characters and one of these two solutions was always applied: change system culture to persian, change app culture to persian. I wonder if it helps

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried to change both system and app culture, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Sure...it works fine in your testing but fails on user's machine.  This suggests that your custom font is not being installed on user's machine causing selection of fallback font which does not have support for Eszett.  Simply another idea to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a problem. Actually our application use comparison and mapping of `System.Windows.Input.Key` and native `ScanCodeShort` to fix HotKeys functionality due to different cultures. As a result - German symbol 'ß' is detected as 'OEM4' key and as a `ScanCodeShort` it's equal to 'OemOpenBrackets'. That's why symbol 'ü' is inputted instead of 'ß'. Now I'm trying to find a solution for this problem, but it seems that's another story.